# Searching with command-T

Tags: search, vim, nerdtree, vim-plugin

When I search some file with command-T it often failes to find it because I'm not in the right directory, so I have to change the directory.

Is it possible to set that command-T will search first in the directories that are bookmarked in `Nerdtree` or somewhere else?

I could change the directory to `/` but this search very large scope of files. When I change the dir to my home directory and I'm looking for something ordinary like `.bashrc` I will find rather many files that are located under `.wine` directory.

In 99 % of time I need to search files in project directories that I actively work with. Can I set these directories in some preferences?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the documentation you can exclude directories from your search:

> ```
>                                             *command-t-wildignore*
>   |'wildignore'|                                 string (default: '')
>
>    Vim's |'wildignore'| setting is used to determine which files should be
>   excluded from listings. This is a comma-separated list of glob patterns.
>   It defaults to the empty string, but common settings include "*.o,*.obj"
>   (to exclude object files) or ".git,.svn" (to exclude SCM metadata
>   directories). For example:
>
>      :set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git
>
>    A pattern such as "vendor/rails/**" would exclude all files and
>   subdirectories inside the "vendor/rails" directory (relative to
>   directory Command-T starts in).
> ```

So if you wanted to exclude a backup dir, you would write:

```
set wildignore+=project/backup
```

in your .vimrc

In addition, to ignore dotfiles/dotdirs you can look into these options:

```
g:CommandTNeverShowDotFiles
g:CommandTScanDotDirectories
g:CommandTMaxDepth
```

These allow you to:
 - ignore dotfiles completely;
 - stop searching recursively in dotdirs;
 - specify at what depth should Command-T stop scanning.

I found this information in [the author's git](http://git.wincent.com/command-t.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/doc/command-t.txt), but you can probably see this document by issuing in vim:

```
:help Command-T
```

(or a similar name)

I did not see any reference to preferences or bookmarks in the plugin.
However if you start vim by opening a file in said project directory you might want to add this line to your .vimrc:

```
    set autochdir
```

This option will set on startup your directory to the current file's directory.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I can partly achieve the goal with commands you suggested. I wish that the author add some opposite command to `wildignore`

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Ctrl-P](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736). I had the same problems as you do and making the change solved them.

I also ignore some folders (in .vimrc):

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
\ 'dir':  '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$',
\ 'file': '\.exe$\|\.so$\|\.dll$' }
```